# Call login got freeze black screen : with facebook loginplugin with unity3d in Android devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've some problem with facebook plugin for unity. When I want to make first login to facebook with andriod. I do it step by step , first I've init facebook and next I've call login then it's seem my device try to call facebook but nothing happen. and it's freeze like that. Not sure that's anybody have same problem like me? But want to know how to solve this issues. Thanks if you reply me.